# Pasar parametro date a un calendario Android

Tags: android, date, calendar, schedule

estoy mostrando en un calendario los eventos que tengo en mi DB pero nose como pasar un parámetro date.

```
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.add(calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 3);//Aqui esta la posicion, (dia en el que quiero que se refleje el titulo del evento)
    events.add(new EventDay(calendar1, DrawableUtils.getCircleDrawableWithText(this, "titulo del evento")));
```

El problema esque yo quiero remplazar esa linea por algo asi,

```
fecha=2018-12-19;
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.add(fecha);
    events.add(new EventDay(calendar1, DrawableUtils.getCircleDrawableWithText(this, "Nombre del evento")));
```

Espero se entienda lo que necesito realizar...
[image: Imagen de referencia a lo que estoy consultando]

Comment: Si entendí bien lo que dices, quieres pasar el String a Calendar verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es pasar la `fecha=2018-12-19;` a `Calendar`, primero tienes que hacer un `parse` de `String` a `Calendar`, intenta lo siguiente:

```
fecha = "2018-12-19";
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat convertirFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD"); //Estableces el formato de la fecha

try {//Haces un try/catch por si ocurre un exception
     calendar1.setTime(convertirFecha.parse(fecha)); //haces la conversión
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```